# Appium unable to locate iOS elements

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile, automation, appium

I am not sure if this is a known issue or just something i’m having with my app.

The issue is that the app i want to write tests for is showing unable to interact with the element for almost all the elements that behind multiple layers and i checked my app it looks like its layered heavily.

what are the solutions to elements that are so far hidden behind layered design?

Do we use for loops to filter through ? what exactly would be recommended

Please if you could advice with examples that would be great

I’m using Appium+webdriverio Javascript

Thank you